# How to print raw std::string/c-style character string in c++

Tags: c++

```
string str = "hello/nblabla/nblabla";
cout << str << endl;
```

how do I make output of this program be:
hello/nblabla/nblabla if I can't use // and generally don't know what string contains. I would like to do the same with c-style char strings as well, and I need to print /0 if it appears in the middle of a c-style string.

I have code something like:

```
fin >> str;
stuff_to_do(str);
cout << str << endl;
```

where fin is a std::ifstream to a file containing data like: 123/nb/t/0/1/"...
I can't reformat this file.

Comment: First of all, and sorry to be a nitpicker, but it's `\ `, not `/`.  (Big difference.)

Comment: Make a lookup table and use it to convert special characters into escape sequences before printing.

Comment: You'll need to write a function that moves along the string a character at a time, printing it a character at a time.  If the character you're looking at is `'\n'`, print it as the two characters `'\'` and `'n'`.  If it's any other special character, print it using some other special character sequence.  Otherwise (if it's a regular character), print it as itself.

Comment: Does your input file contain the two characters `'\'` and `'n'`, or the single character `'\n'`?  (Again, big difference.)

Comment: 2 characters \ and n

Answer (score 2):

Use raw string literal.

```
string str = R"(hello\nblabla\nblabla)";
cout << str << endl;
```

output:
`hello\nblabla\nblabla`

this works for null-terminated strings too!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need an escaping function that takes arbitrary text and escapes it so that it uses the syntax of a C++ string literal (minus the quotes).  Maybe look around the web to see if there's a library already doing this.

There are some conventions to apply because there are multiple ways to escape a character.

I don't love this code, but here's ***an*** implementation I quickly put together to illustrate:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>

const char* staticMap(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case '\a': return "\\a";
        case '\b': return "\\b";
        case '\t': return "\\t";
        case '\n': return "\\n";
        case '\v': return "\\v";
        case '\f': return "\\f";
        case '\r': return "\\r";

        case '\"': return "\\\"";
        case '\'': return "\\\'";
        case '\?': return "\\\?";
        case '\\': return "\\\\";
    }
    return nullptr;
}

std::string escape_cpp(const std::string& input) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (char c : input) {
        const char* str = staticMap(c);
        if (str) { 
            ss << str;
        } else if (!isprint(static_cast<unsigned char>(c))) {
            ss << "\\u" << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(4) << (static_cast<unsigned int>(static_cast<unsigned char>(c)));
        } else {
            ss << c;
        }
    }
    return ss.str();
}

int main() {

    std::string foo("bu\u00ffffalo\n\"\tw\u0000rld\"", 17);
    // Will be printed as written (by convention).
    std::cout << escape_cpp(foo) << std::endl;
}
```